# Using node.js to automatically update MSSQL table on Google Spreadsheet data change

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I would like to ask if there is any way to use node.js or javascript to automatically detect google spreadsheet data change and update the changes in MSSQL database table?

I have read several articles but it all requires the usage of third party applications.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You could set up watch via google drive on that file [watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to changes to a file by using the Watch method in NodeJS.

```
  const res = await drive.files.watch({
    acknowledgeAbuse: false,
    fileId: 'id-value',
    supportsAllDrives: false,   
    requestBody: {
     "address": "my_address",
     "expiration": "my_expiration",
     "id": "my_id",
     "kind": "my_kind",
     "params": {},
     "payload": false,
     "resourceId": "my_resourceId",
     "resourceUri": "my_resourceUri",
     "token": "my_token",
     "type": "my_type"
     }
    },
  });
  console.log(res.data);
```

You can check how to implement the service from the Node JS documentation on https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/drive/classes/Resource$Files-1.html#watch